# Is any Jenkins plugin which could check jobs configuration against recommandation ?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We manage a large Jenkins instance(< 1000 jobs). We made some recommendations about job configuration like number of artifacts to keep, number of jobs to keep etc.

Is there a plugin which could check for jobs that do not respect this recommendation, and report them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the [Groovy Script Console](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Script+Console) or the [Configuration Slicing Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuration+Slicing+Plugin) to accomplish these tasks.

Comment: Is it possible that you post on gist your groovy snippet to do this ?

Comment: There are a lot of examples on the Script Console page, and the Scriptler plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Scriptler+Plugin) has examples too. The Config Slicing Plugin is all hardcoded, and has setup for number of artifacts, etc.